# How to make a Log of a Post in an web Api

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I would like to know how I can know what the Web Api is receiving in the Post that I am sending.

> This is the code I'm using:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://d6dc30b8-0ee0-4-231-b9ee.azurewebsites.net/");
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.lyoness.servicesv1 + json";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date" + tempo); 

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

            }
            MessageBox.Show(json);

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var teste = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(teste);
            }
```

Comment: If you need this just for development you could use Fiddler on the machine emitting the request. It captures what you send to the service and what you receive from it.

Comment: What is the Fiddler ? And how I can do it ?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-wizard. Fiddler is a utility that captures all HTTP trafic from your PC. In it you will see requests your application makes

Comment: And without that can I use any code or anything ?

Comment: If you have access to the web service you can do some logging on that side. But fiddler is still your best bet to achieve this easily. Fiddler is free, and is a tool I use on a daily basis, I highly recommend it.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir But I need to do log with code

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your current model, if you're just after a simple record you could do something like this

```
string url = "https://d6dc30b8-0ee0-4-231-b9ee.azurewebsites.net/";
string method = "POST";
string contentType = "application/json";
string accept = "application/vnd.lyoness.servicesv1 + json";
string headers = "Date";

string myLog = string.Format("URL = {0} | METHOD = {1} | CONTENT TYPE = {2} | ACCEPT = {3} | HEADERS = {4} + {5}", url, method, contentType, accept, headers, tempo);

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Method = method;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = contentType;
httpWebRequest.Accept = accept;
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(headers + tempo);
```

Then you could write `myLog` to a text file or something to keep a record of it.